# iOS Facebook messenger placeholer message content in url_scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-messenger

In my app I would like to open the Messenger app with a specific user id and a plceholder message. So far i only came up with this:

```
    NSString* messengerURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb-messenger://user-thread/%@", facebookId];

    NSURL *messengerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:messengerURLString];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:messengerURL]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:messengerURL];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"can't open URL");
    }
```

How can i add a message content to this url scheme?

Thanks,

Zoli

Comment: Use the Message Dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog . Using that will allow you to share a link but nothing else